# Maintaining List Item state on :hover

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am working with some CSS for a small menu idea I have.

<strike>I am hoping that when ready, I can hover over the link 'Test 1' and the Test 1 content displays in the **#content** div. And if you hover over 'Test 2' link then Test 2 content appears.</strike>

I was also hoping if it's possible that when I move the cursor over to the **#content** div (from a link) that it will maintain the content in that area for that link.

**Is this possible?**

Many thanks for any helpers with this.

Here is my basic HTML:
http://jsfiddle.net/PjHnM/1/

---

**UPDATE**

I have an example I found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/88nKd/
but I'm still unsure how to maintain state when I hover into the content part.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Divs</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {margin:0;padding:0}
#main {height:100px;width:400px;float:left;background:#eee;}
#main ul {height:100px;float:left;background:#999}
#main ul li a {width:100px;display:block;background:#333;color:#fff}
#main ul li a:hover {background:#777}
#content {height:100px;}
#content div {float:left}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <div style="display:none">Test 1 Content</div>
        <div style="display:none">Test 2 Content</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can't do this in plain CSS. you need the aid of JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Divs</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {margin:0;padding:0}
#main {height:100px;width:400px;float:left;background:#eee;}
#main ul {height:100px;float:left;background:#999}
#main ul li a {width:100px;display:block;background:#333;color:#fff}
#main ul li a:hover {background:#777}
#content {height:100px;}
#content div {height:100px;}
</style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#test1").mouseenter(function(){$("#content1").show();}).mouseleave(function(){$("#content1").hide();});
$("#test2").mouseenter(function(){$("#content2").show();}).mouseleave(function(){$("#content2").hide();});

$("#content1").mouseenter(function(){$("#content1").show();}).mouseleave(function(){$("#content1").hide();});
$("#content2").mouseenter(function(){$("#content2").show();}).mouseleave(function(){$("#content2").hide();});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void;" id="test1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void;" id="test2">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <div style="display:none" id="content1">Test 1 Content</div>
        <div style="display:none" id="content2">Test 2 Content</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

** UPDATED **
Is this what did you mean?

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try in a sec :-) Sorry my question above has been edited a little as I managed to find a similar partial solution.

Comment: This is new updated version. I think, this is what did you mean.

Comment: Tried it and it works great. However, I'm also wondering if it's possible when I hover over to the #content box that it keeps the text in place.

Comment: Checked update :) I think we're 98.4% there :D I noticed however when we hover over 'Test 2' link then on to the #content div that it doesn't keep the Text 2 content in place. Do you see this issue too?

Comment: Legendary stuff, M1K1O. I think it's safe to say you have just made my weekend. Many, many thanks for your patience and skills. Have a good day :-)

Answer (score 1):

you need some changes in your markup and jquery(or plain js if you go that way) make it work.

```
<head>
<script>
$("#menuItems li").mouseover(function(){
        var className = $(this).attr("class");
        $("#content div").hide();
        $("#content").find("."+className).show();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
    <ul id="menuItems">
        <li><a class="test1" href="">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="test2" href="">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="test1" style="display:none">Test 1 Content</div>
        <div class="test2" style="display:none">Test 2 Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This will work for n number of menu elements as long as u follow the markup notation